# Javascript: Why an instance is able to change the array but not other properties that are defined in the prototype?

Tags: javascript

I am confused why an `instance` of a `Person`, for example, `person1` is able to change the property `jobs`, which is an `array`, defined in `Person.prototype` but not other properties like `name` and `height`. This is seen when `person2` calls the properties from `Person.prototype` after `person1` tries to modify its `properties`. I appreciate any ideas or thoughts. Thank you.

```
function Person(){

}

Person.prototype = {
    constructor : Person,
    name: "Hello",
    height: 6,
    jobs: ['developer', 'student'],
    getInfo: function(){
        alert("My name is "+this.name+" and my height is: "+this.height+" feet");
    }
}

var person1 = new Person();
person1.height = 5;
person1.name = "World";
person1.jobs.push('cook');
alert(person1.jobs); //developer, student, cook
alert(person1.height); //5
alert(person1.name); //World

var person2 = new Person();
alert(person2.height); //6
alert(person2.jobs); //developer, student, cook
alert(person2.name); //Hello
```

Comment: Why do you set the Person's constructor to Person?

Comment: @Bálint: Because that's how JavaScript defines the `constructor` property on prototype objects (to the extent it does, which is fairly minimal).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder By writing `Person.prototype = {...}` you already decare, that it's constructor is the Person function

Comment: @Bálint: No, you don't. If the OP had left `constructor` out of the object he assigned to `Person.prototype`, `person1.constructor` would refer to `Object` (because it would inherit `Object.prototype.constructor` indirectly, since `Person.prototype` has no `constructor` prop). But it should refer to `Person`. By default, all functions with a `prototype` property have a `constructor` property on it referring back to the function. If you replace the object on `prototype`, correctly assigning `constructor` is the right thing to do. Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/gh169n0k/ :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, yeah, he uses an object to create the prototypes. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you do

```
person1.height = 5;
```

The object `person1` refers to gets its **own** `height` property, which hides the `height` it inherits from its prototype.

But when you do:

```
person1.jobs.push('cook');
```

you're not *assigning* to `jobs`, you're just changing the state of what `jobs` refers to (the array). So you're changing the one on the prototype.

If you did:

```
person1.jobs = ['cook'];
```

that would be like our `height` example, `person1` would get its *own* `jobs` property. If you want to keep the jobs that the prototype had, you could copy the array first:

```
person1.jobs = person1.jobs.slice();
person1.jobs.push('cook');
```

Let's look at what's going on in memory:

When you've created your `Person` function and the object on its `Person.prototype` property, we have this in memory:

```
       +------------------------------------------+
       |                                          |
       |                                          |
        \  +------------+                         |
Person---->| (function) |                         |
           +------------+     +---------------+   |              
           | prototype  |---->|   (object)    |   |              
           +------------+     +---------------+   |              
                              | constructor   |---+              
                              | getInfo       |------>(not shown)
                              | name: "Hello" |                  
                              | height: 6     |      +----------------+
                              | jobs          |----->|     (array)    |
                              +---------------+      +----------------+
                                                     | 0: "developer" |
                                                     | 1: "student"   |
                                                     +----------------+
```

Then we do

```
var person1 = new Person();
```

and we have this:

```
       +----------------------------------------------+
       |                                              |
       |                                              |
        \  +------------+                             |
Person---->| (function) |                             |
           +------------+         +---------------+   |              
           | prototype  |-------->|   (object)    |   |              
           +------------+       / +---------------+   |              
                               |  | constructor   |---+              
                               |  | getInfo       |------>(not shown)
                               |  | name: "Hello" |                  
                               |  | height: 6     |      +----------------+
                               |  | jobs          |----->|     (array)    |
                               |  +---------------+      +----------------+
                               |                         | 0: "developer" |
                               |                         | 1: "student"   |
                               |                         +----------------+
           +---------------+   |
person1--->|   (object)    |   |
           +---------------+   |
           | [[Prototype]] |---+
           +---------------+
```

When you do this:

```
person1.height = 5;
```

`person1` gets its *own* `height` (everything else stays the same):

```
                              (to Person.prototype)
           +---------------+   |
person1--->|   (object)    |   |
           +---------------+   |
           | [[Prototype]] |---+
           | height: 5     |
           +---------------+
```

But doing `person1.jobs.push('cook');` just changes the state of the array `jobs` points to:

```
       +----------------------------------------------+
       |                                              |
       |                                              |
        \  +------------+                             |
Person---->| (function) |                             |
           +------------+         +---------------+   |              
           | prototype  |-------->|   (object)    |   |              
           +------------+       / +---------------+   |              
                               |  | constructor   |---+              
                               |  | getInfo       |------>(not shown)
                               |  | name: "Hello" |                  
                               |  | height: 6     |      +----------------+
                               |  | jobs          |----->|     (array)    |
                               |  +---------------+      +----------------+
                               |                         | 0: "developer" |
                               |                         | 1: "student"   |
                               |                      +->| 2: "cook"      |
                               |                      |  +----------------+
           +---------------+   |                      |
person1--->|   (object)    |   |                      |
           +---------------+   |          NOTE WHAT   |
           | [[Prototype]] |---+          CHANGED ----+
           | height: 5     |
           +---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `jobs`, you are mutating the object rather than re-assigning the object.

In case of `person1.height = 5;`, you are assigning. So, it assigns to `person1` but not to the prototype. In case of `jobs`, you are just mutating, so the effects are visible. Go through *prototypical inheritance* to learn more about it.